# Add data-attribute to selectize.js options

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, selectize.js

I am using selectize.js for my project. But I have problems with data-attributes. I want to add data-attributes to the select options.
I have default select like this:

```
<option data-open-balance="false" selected="selected" value="1">PNP.SI.080416</option>
```

But When I add selectize to this select, it becomes:

```
<div data-value="1" data-selectable="" class="selected">PNP.SI.080416</div>
```

I see that its "item object" only get value, and text. So, how can I add other data-attributes to its item object?

Answer (score 14):

I've looked at docs and they say that if you want to add custom attributes to your elements, you should use `dataAttr` option, by default it `data-data`. So in your case code will look somethnig like this:

**HTML**

```
<select>
    <option data-data='{"openBalance": true}' selected="selected" value="1">PNP.SI.080416</option>
</select>
```

### **JS**

Here we provide custom render method to draw `options` with attributes we need:

```
$('select').selectize({
    render: {
        option: function (data, escape) {
            return "<div data-open-balance='" + data.openBalance + "'>" + data.text + "</div>"
        }
    }
})
```

**UDATE**

As [Kyborek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1276062/kyborek) notes that in order to secure your site or web app from [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), you should use `escape` method in render callback. Also use it if you want to display `html` tags in `data.text`. Updated example will look something like this:

```
$('select').selectize({
    render: {
        option: function (data, escape) {
            return "<div data-open-balance='" + escape(data.openBalance) + "'>" + escape(data.text) + "</div>"
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: If someone want to use php can use this `<option data-data='<?php echo json_encode( $your_option ); ?>' value='<?php echo $value; ?>'><?php echo $text; ?></option>`. It's very important the use of single quote ' in data-data tag, because JSON use double quote " for the structure.

Comment: Downvoted because the JS solution is subject to XSS. If the data.text contains html tags or simple `>` it will break the dropdown. For this escape function is provided such that you can escape data before returning them. The resulting return should be: `return "<div data-open-balance='" + escape(data.openBalance) + "'>" + escape(data.text) + "</div>"`

Comment: @Kyborek although, in my opinion, it was not related to question, I've updated my answer with your notes, thanks.