# selectize.js lockOptgroupOrder throwing exception

Tags: selectize.js

I have a selectize where I set optgroups, give them an $order, and then try to set lockOptgroupOrder, which ends up throwing an exception: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$order' of undefined".

This all works perfectly before I try to use lockOptgroupOrder (except that it sorts wrong).  I cannot figure out why it can't find $order, when I'm clearly passing $order in as part of optgroups.  (I've also tried setting `optgroupOrder: ['first', 'recents', 'favorites', 'all']` with no luck.)

```
var stuff = $('#stuff').selectize({
    optgroups: [
        {value: 'first', label: '', $order: 1},
        {value: 'recents', label: 'Recents', $order: 2},
        {value: 'favorites', label: 'Favorites', $order: 3},
        {value: 'all', label: 'All', $order: 4}
    ],
    optgroupField: 'type',
    lockOptgroupOrder: true,
    //more things like load() and onChange()...
});
```

The error:

[image: Uncaught TypeError]

It's breaking in this loop:

[image]

I have exhausted all other forms of researching this error.  Has anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after many, many hours of googling, chrome debugging, and general crying, I figured out the issue and now I'm posting my solution in case anyone else comes across this error.

Thanks to this discussion board:

[lockOptgroupOrder breaks onChange](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/issues/703)

I was able to piece together that one of my data elements was missing a 'type' field (optgroupField).  I stepped through all 1350 options before realizing that it was actually the default option I added to the select before turning it into a selectize.  In this instance, I need this option to stay, so I can't just get rid of that line of html.  But I also can't add a "type" attribute to the option, or even a data-type attribute, it doesn't pass it along.

Finally I figured out from this discussion board:

[Add data-attribute to selectize.js options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36512536/add-data-attribute-to-selectize-js-options)

that I can assign a data-data attribute and pass it the name and value, and then it would pass that attribute along when it turns into a selectize.  So my final solution was to add what I needed via the option before it turns into a selectize:

`<option selected disabled value="default" data-data='{"type":"first"}'>The Stuff</option>`

May this help some other poor soul from having to go through this in the future.